# android layout 50% above and below boundary

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I can't find words to describe my problem exactly. I was thinking about this problem few hours without any solution.

Here is an image for better understating of my problem.

[image: problem]

So my viewB is below viewA. Problematic part is how to position viewC in xml so that viewA and viewB connecting line splits my viewC into half.

Is there any easy solution for this problem ? I can't get even close with my xml code.

Some kind of custom view already built ? 
I tried to search for the answer but with no luck.

Any suggestions for solving this problem are really helpful.

Comment: Do you only want to use xml? If you can add the 3rd view programatically, it might be comparatively easier. You can sex x and y co-ordinate of the third view before adding it,

Comment: originally my plan was only to use xml. Because this will be my row in listview .. if I have to build my view from scratch it is more complicated.. I have to measure viewC height and then position it programmatically . Maybe someone already build something like this ?

Comment: Do you know hight of view C or you use wrap content?

Comment: wrap_content and it contains centered text inside 9pacthed background

Comment: And what about viewB and viewC ? There are in relative layout or in linear layout? Do you set high for them or are they also have wrap_content as high?

Comment: heightViewA + heightViewb = screenWidth  ( ratio 1:1 ) ...  and also heightViewA will take 2/3  and heightViewB 1/3

Comment: You can overlay it on top with dummy invisible views providing the weights, just as the separator itself is layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its little bit complicated one But it will give you the desired result

Hope it will help to solve the question

[image]

Xml Code :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:text="View A" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff00ffe8"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <TextView android:text="View B" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffe83b"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0000ffe8"
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textColor="#0000"
            />

        <LinearLayout android:text="View B" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00ffe83b"
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/a"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="6.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textColor="#0000"
            android:weightSum="3.5"
            >
            <TextView android:text="View C" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffff5b25"
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/a"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#0000ffe8"
                android:id="@+id/a2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="#0000"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is this going to work with height set to wrap_content ? because I don't need full screen view

Comment: You can can change root Layout height it will work or u can set specific height